# Come mai 'Ebola' si sente spesso nominare senza articolo?

Tags: articles

Io direi *l'Ebola*, o *il virus dell'Ebola*. Probabilmente tenderei anche a scriverlo senza la maiuscola.

Si tratta tecnicamente di un nome proprio, ma perché non viene "comunizzato" come le altre patologie infettive, quali ad esempio *l'influenza*? Quale decisione determina la mancanza dell'articolo?

A titolo di esempio, giornali scrivono cose come "si teme per la vita della persona X infettata *da Ebola* ..." (invece che *dall'Ebola*). Come dicevo inoltre, non è chiaro nemmeno se si debba usare la maiuscola o no.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

come proposto [qui](http://blog.terminologiaetc.it/2014/10/07/articolo-nomi-patologie/), presumibilmente non usare l'articolo è un effetto del riprendere, diciamo, "letteralmente" i testi in inglese.

Answer (score 5):

Credo che si possa fare riferimento alla figura retorica della "personificazione" per spiegare sia la mancanza di articolo che la lettera maiuscola.

Penso infatti che si tenda a dare dell'ebola una rappresentazione tale per cui il virus viene percepito come una "entità" cosciente (pensiamo al fatto che hanno anche realizzato i peluche del virus ebola...)

Certamente per l'uomo questa malattia è pericolosissima, ma il virus di per sé sta solo facendo quello che sa fare per sopravvivere.

Answer (score 3):

Vi sono costrutti in italiano coinvolgenti i nomi di malattie che sottilmente trattano le stesse come un qualcosa di "uncountable" delle quali i vari casi costituiscono mere istanze. Quando si dice "affetto da ebola" o "in presenza di varicella", ad esempio, si intende che dette malattie si pensando come una qualche forma di contaminazione estesa, della quale il caso in questione costituisce solo una piccola parte, quasi si parlasse di un unico fluido o sporcizia che possa infettare di volta in volta organismi differenti.