# La parola "Ebola" in italiano è sdrucciola o piana?

Tags: accents, pronunciation

Leggendo [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/3546/707) mi sono accorta di non saper come pronunciare "Ebola" in italiano, cioè, di non saper dove mettere l'accento tonico in questo vocabolo. In spagnolo, "Ébola" è una parola sdrucciola, mentre in catalano "Ebola" è piana. Com'è in italiano?

Comment: Secondo me 'ebola' si pronuncia come 'élite', però noi italiani non facciamo molto caso a queste cose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In italiano si pronuncia <s>Ébola</s> Èbola. In altre lingue, come in inglese, ebòla.

Comment: Ébola con l'accento acuto, quindi con la E chiusa?

Comment: Io l'ho quasi sempre sentito pronunciare così, ma credo vari anche in base all'accento delle persone

Comment: Scusate, ho sbagliato. Leggendo sul sito della treccani, si pronuncia "Èbola": http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/virus-di-ebola_(Lessico-del-XXI-Secolo)/

Comment: @WalterTross: Ho trovato [questa pronuncia](http://www.forvo.com/word/ebola/#it) della parola Ebola in italiano.