# Accento delle parole straniere

Tags: accents, foreign-words

Da chi/come è deciso l'accento delle parole straniere o delle parole nuove? Domanda ispirata da [La parola "Ebola" in italiano è sdrucciola o piana?](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/3547/la-parola-ebola-in-italiano-%C3%A8-sdrucciola-o-piana)

Comment: Dall'uso, non c'è alcuna regola. Per esempio è purtroppo molto comune sentire “ollìnclusive” mentre l'accento dell'inglese *inclusive* è sulla “u”.

Comment: Ah qui si apre un mondo di parole inglesi pronunciate sbagliate in italiano che portano a ripetere l'errore quando si parla in inglese... io per esempio sbaglio sempre "bowling"

Comment: Hai messo il dito nella piaga. In Italia non esiste l'Accademia Reale Italiana che giustamente si prende cura di questi aspetti.

Comment: @carlodurso Che cos'è l'«Accademia Reale Italiana»?

Comment: Dovrebbe essere la prominente Istituzione sulle tematiche relative alla lingua italiana. Comparabile con la [Real Academia Española](http://www.rae.es/) e la [Académie française](http://www.xn--acadmie-franaise-npb1a.fr/).

Comment: @carlodusrso Ma in Italia non c'è un re. Magari l'Accademia Presidenziale Italiana?

Answer (score 1):

La massima autorità nel campo dello studio della lingua italiana è l'[Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/pagina-d-entrata), che fra i propri propositi ha proprio quello di catalogare i neologismi, fissandone le convenzioni morfografiche e fonetiche. Anche se non è un'istituzione ufficiale dello Stato italiano, la sua autorevolezza è di fatto indiscussa. [Qui una breve descrizione su Wikipedia](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accademia_della_Crusca).

Comment: Attenzione: giusto ma, tanto per chiarire, la Crusca non è un'“autorità” nel senso che possa (o voglia) dettare norme in campo linguistico. È un organismo di ricerca che studia il presente, il passato, il futuro della lingua (così come l'INFN non dice ai fenomeni fisici come devono comportarsi, bensì li indaga).

Comment: Ho visitato spesso il sito della Crusca e non mi pare proprio che si limiti a studiare senza tentar di influenzare.

Comment: @Formagella: Non mi sembra di aver parlato di “influenzare” o meno. Ricordavo solo che la Crusca non è un'autorità, bensì un ente di ricerca. Poi è chiaro che un esperto di un argomento esprimerà delle opinioni su ciò che conosce bene, e guai se non lo facesse, altrimenti lascerebbe campo libero a chi ne sa di meno.

Answer (score 1):

Secondo l'[Enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/forestierismi_%28Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano%29/):

> «Oggi sono i mezzi di comunicazione di massa che hanno un ruolo decisivo nella stabilizzazione grafica e fonetica dei forestierismi, per i quali si tende ad approssimarsi il più possibile al modello alloglotto, talora anche nel caso di voci che già avevano assunto una forma adattata.»

Dunque, come è stato detto da @egreg, l'accento dei forestierismi è deciso dall'uso, ma sono principalmente i mezzi di comunicazione di massa quelli che stabiliscono tale uso.

Mi sembra curiosa l'affermazione «si tende ad approssimarsi il più possibile al modello alloglotto» perché nel caso precedentemente discusso del vocabolo «Ebola» non è stato così, come si può vedere da [questo articolo](http://www.salon.com/2014/09/28/the_problem_with_ebola_the_troubling_xenophobic_language_of_disease/).